# Grouping and exporting excel rows using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

This is using Python.

I have an excel sheet that in its most basic form looks like this

```
New York    Cup a   3
Stockholm   Plate b 5
Madrid  Cup a   2
New York    Cup b   5
New York    Plate a 8
Madrid  Cup b   9
Stockholm   Plate a 2
Stockholm   Cup a   5
Stockholm   Cup b   3
Madrid  Cup a   5
New York    Plate a 8
```

I want to group the locations together so that all the new yorks are together and madrids etc and export them to separate excel sheets called new york, madrid, stockholm. With the same info on the rows. So basically just a copy and paste of the row into a new excel sheet named after that row. Then I want to add all cups together as one and all plates as one on the second page of each one. Would make sense to do this before exporting the data right?

End result 3 excel sheets named, containing only their data, and some easy math on the second sheet.

The real excel sheet is dealing with 15000 rows 50 locations and 100 items. These change so would have to be a procedural way. New york might be Toronto next time.

So far I have been able to group them by pandas but every attempt after that as failed.

New to pandas so I thought this one would be relatively easy to do.

```
import pandas as pd

stock_report_excel = "small_stores_blocked_stock_value.xlsx"

df_soh = pd.read_excel(stock_report_excel, sheet_name='SOH')
df_stores = df_soh.groupby(['Site Name'])
```

## guess loop to add to sheet

## adding of the items to sheet 2

## exporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the problem

```
import pandas as pd

import os

file = "yourfile.xlsx"

extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]

filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]

abpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(file))

df=pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="sheetname")

colpick = "column to extract" 

cols=list(set(df[colpick].values))


def sendtofile(cols):

    for i in cols:
        df[df[colpick] == i].to_excel("{}/exported/{}.xlsx".format(abpath, i), sheet_name=i, index=False)
return
```

Answer (score 0):

While not very clear what is your desired purpose, I guess [Pandas MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) DataFrame may be helpful for you. I write some simple codes below and wish could guide you further.

```
import pandas as pd
sites=pd.Series(['New York','Stockholm','Madrid','New York','New York','Madrid','Stockholm','Stockholm','Stockholm','Madrid','New York'])
col2=pd.Series(['Cup','Plate','Cup','Cup','Plate','Cup','Plate','Cup','Cup','Cup','Plate'])
col3=pd.Series(['a','b','a','b','a','b','a','a','b','a','a'])
col4=pd.Series([3,5,2,5,8,9,2,5,3,5,8])
data=pd.DataFrame({'sites':sites,'col2':col2,'col3':col3,'col4':col4})
# You can of course replce all the codes above with Pandas read related functions.
data1 = data.set_index(['sites','col2','col3']) # Set as MultiIndex DataFrame.
data1.loc[('New York'),:] # This will give you all the 'New York' data
data1.loc[('New York','Cup'),:] # This will give you all the 'New York' & 'Cup' data.
# Retrieving all the 'Cup' data is a bit tricky, see the following
idx=pd.IndexSlice
data1.loc[idx[:,'Cup'],:]
```

Output as follows.

```
# data
        sites   col2 col3  col4
0    New York    Cup    a     3
1   Stockholm  Plate    b     5
2      Madrid    Cup    a     2
3    New York    Cup    b     5
4    New York  Plate    a     8
5      Madrid    Cup    b     9
6   Stockholm  Plate    a     2
7   Stockholm    Cup    a     5
8   Stockholm    Cup    b     3
9      Madrid    Cup    a     5
10   New York  Plate    a     8
# data1
                      col4
sites     col2  col3
New York  Cup   a        3
Stockholm Plate b        5
Madrid    Cup   a        2
New York  Cup   b        5
          Plate a        8
Madrid    Cup   b        9
Stockholm Plate a        2
          Cup   a        5
                b        3
Madrid    Cup   a        5
New York  Plate a        8
# data1.loc[('New York'),:]
            col4
col2  col3
Cup   a        3
      b        5
Plate a        8
      a        8
# data1.loc[('New York','Cup'),:]
      col4
col3
a        3
b        5
# data1.loc[idx[:,'Cup'],:]
                     col4
sites     col2 col3
New York  Cup  a        3
Madrid    Cup  a        2
New York  Cup  b        5
Madrid    Cup  b        9
Stockholm Cup  a        5
               b        3
Madrid    Cup  a        5
```

If you do not want to see any warnings and want to keep high performance, you can all use `idx` and explicit coding, which are:

```
data1.loc[idx['New York',:,:],:]
data1.loc[idx['New York','Cup',:],:]
data1.loc[idx['','Cup',:],:]
```

Your next step is to write these data selections into a separate sheet. I am not very familiar with that because I always write data into text files. For example, write one of them into a csv file is as simple as `data1.loc[idx['New York','Cup',:],:].to_csv('result.csv',index=False)`. I recommend you search your desired functions.
Hope this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Sorry if it wasn't clear.
So end goal is to get each row of site mentioned to become its own excel sheet.

New York   ' Cup a'   3
New York    'Cup b '  5
New York    'Plate a' 8
New York    'Plate a' 8
This data into a new excel sheet called new york.
On page 2 of the data sheet ex add all cups irregardless of a or b, so
page 2
new york 'cups total' 8
new york 'plates total' 16

This would be the same for each location so same for madrid etc.

Currently it is being copy and pasted out of the sheets. But I would like to automate the process

Comment: Based on the information you further provided here, I believe Pandas MultiIndex Selection will probably meet your ends. I am now changing the codes I previously provided above and hope it can guide you further.